# How do I print array values in form field in PHP?

Tags: php, html, arrays, forms, hidden-field

I want to print the value of form fields using an array. I have two fields in file1.php, **name** and **email**, which I am passing to file2.php using post and storing it in an array.

```
<?php 
    $name = $_post['name']
    $email = $_post['email];
    function personal($name, $email) {
        $return = array($name, $email);
        print_r($return); //Output(Array ( [0] => alisha [1] => alisha@gmail.com )
        echo implode('<br>', $return);  //Output alisha      alisha@gmail.com

?>
```

How do I print these values, **alisha** and **alisha@gmail.com**, in the file1.php when the user go to the previous page using the submit button without using a session and a cookie?

```
<input type=text name=name value="**print alisha here array[0]**">
<input type=text name=email value="**print alisha@gmail.com here array[1]**">
```

Comment: value="<?php echo $return[0]?>", but i don't understand why you should use array when you have the variables allready ($name, $email))?

Comment: @bksi - also has them as $_POST['email'] & $_POST['name']. Any reason why they have gone through 2 variable changes for the same values?

Comment: @bksi -its because i am passing this variable to many pages using hidden variable & function and at last store all the values in array. Without array i am able to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" name="name" value="<?= $return[0]; ?>" />

<input type="text" name="email" value="<?= $return[1]; ?>" />
```

You just need to echo the array key (0 for name, 1 for email).

Comment: I tried it      `Name: <input type="text"  name="name" value="<?php echo $return[0]; ?>"><br>` but its not working